How to add a RCLShared library to MAUI project without causing runtime issues
I have a .net8 class library RCLshared and a .net8 MAUI blazor hybrid project (also blazor project no issues here).
Initially added RCLshared to MAUI following this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/class-libraries?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
After adding nuget packages to the RCLshared lib the MAUI build failed : NETSDK1082    There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier
Removing the packages breaks the web version.
Removing the RCLshared as a project reference and adding it as a shared project reference fixes the build issues
However when i want to use anything in the wwwroot (image/css ect) it no longer servers them _content/RCLShared/css/app.css due to it no longer being a project ref
Questions:

Should i be adding nuget packages to the shared lib ?
Is there a workaround for adding the project reference to not cause build issues ?
should the MAUI run independantly from the web version (not reuse services/pages/styles from RCLShared)
Should i use a packages solution and reference them this way (i feel this will lead to the result of a broken MAUI build)
any ideas ?

EDIT
Shared packages

maui packages


May I know what nuget packages you've added to the RCLshared lib?

Hi Alexandar i have added the packages to the question

Thanks for the update. Are the packages(in the first screenshot) installed in the Maui Class Library and the second are installed in the Maui Blazor Hybrid App?

first screenshot is shared project second is maui


Components can be shared in a Razor class library (RCL) across projects. Include components and static assets in an app from: Another project in the solution, a referenced .NET library, a NuGet package. 2. I installed the nuget packages you provided, however, there's no building error. 3. When referring to another project in your solution, you have to use "_content" in the reference to get it.

